# PHP - mysqli_set_charset() and SQL injections

Tags: php, mysql, security

I have read several articles here and elsewhere that say that using mysqli_set_charset() can prevent SQL injections if every string that the user inputs (and that is used in a database query) is first put into mysqli_real_escape_string().

But then, nothing seems to be safer than prepared statements. Not being an expert in any of these, is it true that these lines in the code

```
$input = "This is an input string";
mysqli_set_charset($conn, 'utf8');
$input = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $input);
```

are enough to prevent SQL injections? Of course, I am assuming that really every input is escaped. As of my current understanding, it should be, but I am doubtful whether my current understanding is enough. I know that there are cases in which mysqli_real_escape_string() can fail, but these seem to depend on a vulnerable charset (according to my current understanding).

Comment: `nothing seems to be safer than prepared statements` - Think of Prepared statements happening in 2 steps. The first step when you prepare the query is when the DB compiles the SQL it will run, the second step submitting the data to that already compiled SQL.  So you see there is no chance the DB can mistake any value as SQL (because it already has the fully complied query -{minus} the data).  Just encoding it only has one step, so if anything goes wrong it's complied as SQL - that is the basic diffrence

Comment: Also it's much easier to miss a step when escaping, then when preparing.  Generally the SQL will work rather or not you escape every piece of data.  With Prepared statements there is no question as to if you missed any data because it simply won't work.  There is also a small performance benefit in preparing.  Even more when you consider all  the escaping that doesn't need to be done.  It's generally less code to write, less error prone, less buggy. etc... there is no benefit to not prepare them.

Comment: Yes, that is basically my current understanding of the matter. But my above question still remains. Of course, I could just replace very input with a prepared statement, but that would take some time because there are queries that are dynamically put together, so I don't always know ahead of time how long the query is gonna be. It would still be possible, but if the other way should turn out to be safe as well, then I could just leave it as it is. I have escaped everything.

Comment: `I don't always know ahead of time how long the query is gonna be` - you can do the same thing with prepared statements.  You just do placeholders and keep an array of input data as you build them.  The thing you have to ask yourself is "Do you know for an absolute fact that every single piece of data has been escaped properly"  The only way to answer that is to go through the code.  By which time you might as well fix it.  If I know that every single query I write is prepared, then I know the answer to that without having to look.

Comment: Indeed, but I am pretty damn sure I have escaped everything. Nevertheless, before proceeding and independent of what I am eventually going to do, I want to clear the basic question of whether this is completely safe in the first place.

I did not want to allude that I would be hampered by not knowing ahead of time how long the query is going to be.

Answer (score 2):

The key here is to never, ever use `mysqli_real_escape_string` unless you have a very good reason. Composing a simple query is not one.

`mysqli_real_escape_string` *can* prevent SQL injection. Prepared statements with placeholder values *will* prevent SQL injection. This is an important distinction.

Consider this code:

```
 $a = $_POST['a'];
 $b = $_POST['b'];
 $c = $_POST['c'];
 $d = $_POST['d'];
 // ...
 $a = $conn->real_escape_string($a);
 $a = $conn->real_escape_string($b);
 $c = $conn->real_escape_string($c);
 $d = $conn->real_escape_string($d);

 $conn->query("INSERT INTO x (a,b,c,d) VALUES ('$a', '$b', '$c', '$d')");
```

This has a SQL injection bug in it due to a tiny mistake. That it's a tiny mistake doesn't matter, even a single hole like this can be enough to completely compromise your application.

Instead, use prepared statements with placeholder values:

```
 $stmt = $conn->prepare('INSERT INTO x (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?)');
 $stmt->bind_param('ssss', $_POST['a'], $_POST['b'], $_POST['c'], $_POST['d']);
 $stmt->execute();
```

Even if you make a mistake here the worst that can happen is the query fails or you insert the wrong data. You don't have a SQL injection bug. Your application can't be compromised. I'd even go so far as to suggest you use *single quotes when defining queries* so you're never tempted to use variable interpolation, which is a form of injection.

It's also worth noting that the `bind_param` method is **less code** and **more readable**. There's really no reason to do use manual escaping for things like this.

Comment: Yes, having a minor mistake somewhere is always something to worry about. That is one reason why I am pondering to replace all mysqli_real_escape_string() with prepared statements. But apart from that and supposing that there is no mistake and I am using utf8 as encoding, is mysqli_real_escape_string() safe?

Comment: "Assuming there is no mistake" is how virtually all catastrophic problems occur. The principle here is you really have to foul up to get an injection with placeholder code, you have to go out of your way to do something bad. With interpolation or concatenation a simple, invisible mistake can do you in. Replace all your statements, every single last one, with a proper, prepared version of same.

Comment: You want your coding mistakes to *fail safe* and not *fail dangerously, possibly destroying the application, the company and even my own career* because that's what happens when a SQL injection hole gets exploited. People cut corners and [very bad things happen](https://codecurmudgeon.com/wp/sql-injection-hall-of-shame/).

Comment: I don't work for a company, I am working on my own website, but nevertheless, some jerk destroying my database is no joke. The more I think about it, the more I am inclined to go through the whole code and insert prepared statements. Just for my understanding of things, in principle, when used properly, mysqli_real_escape_string() with a non-vulnerable charset (think utf8) would be safe, right?

Comment: No, it's not safe. It's only an approximation of safe under certain unreasonable assumptions, like you'll never make any mistakes. It's also way more work to do than to just use prepared statements with placeholder values. Do it correctly the first time. Develop good habits here. This is important.

Comment: `I'd even go so far as to suggest you use single quotes when defining queries so you're never tempted to use variable interpolation`  - That is what I do.  The mistake in this case is the second `$a = $conn->real_escape_string($b);` Which leaves `$b` unescaped.  This is very easy to do, and I say that as someone that started out in 2008 using `mysql_`  I used `mysqli`(maybe 2010 ish) for about a year, then I started using `PDO` for various reasons.

Comment: With using single quotes, do you mean $query = 'SELECT * FROM table WHERE etc'; So, single quotes around the query?

Comment: I mean making it an absolute priority to avoid putting `$` values directly in your query using either interpolation or concatenation. 99.9% of the SQL injection problems in PHP come from failing to **use prepared statements with placeholder values**. These ensure that the data is sent through *independently* of the query and there's zero risk of injection if done in a disciplined manner.

Comment: I"m just suggesting single quotes as a way to fight the urge to do `'INSERT INTO x VALUES ('$y')'` because it will error out safely due to syntax errors instead of working and exposing a SQL injection hole. If you go out of your way  with `VALUES("$y")` then you insert literal `$y` which is broken but harmless.

Comment: I've just replaced a mysqli_real_escape_string() with a prepared statement. Then I came up with the idea of attacking my own website via SQl injection (harmless ones that don't mess up the database, of course). I've injected ' and ' or '1'='1' and in both cases the site told me that there are no search results (the normal no results page). Does that mean that I am save? Regardless, I think I will convertthe remaining instances to prepared statements, too.

Comment: SQL injection takes many forms and serves many purposes. Sometimes it's to bypass normal filtering, like during a login, to force the database to retrieve the wrong record, like an admin's instead of a regular user. Testing tools like [SQLmap](http://sqlmap.org) can help as they have a far broader suite of injection tools than `1'='1'`.

Comment: Remember SQL injection is just [one of the things you need to be vigilant about](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/OWASP_Cheat_Sheet_Series) when making a site. XSS, CSRF and more are also prominent concerns.